# Are there any reasons that downloading files as a zip would exclude files?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, iis

We have an issue with downloading packages in courses inside our learning management system. For example in course ABC123 if you go to the Files area in the control panel and check any of the boxes for SoftChalk Modules M1, M2, M3, M4, or M5, and click download package, you'll download a zip package of that content folder that is significantly smaller than the reported size once the files are extracted.

In addition, the extracted zip is missing files that should be there and are confirmed to be in the Files area as you drill down through the folders. The files that are missing are confirmed to not be corrupt.

It affects the instructors abilities to properly download their package for editing in SoftChalk Create because when loading the index.html file it says it can't read from XML files because they're missing of course.

The IIS7.5 download limit is set to 314 MB so I don't think that's the issue. Are there any OS, Server, or Network related reasons that cause this behavior?

Comment: Have you contacted the software vendor?

Comment: Yes but I just like to cover all bases at the same time while waiting for responses to different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite common for anti-virus software to scan archives (which includes ZIP files) as they are downloaded. I would check your anti-virus software on both the server and clients for false positives before tearing your hair out over this.

Comment: This is a great idea and I wish it was the issue but neither client nor server have anti virus software installed.

Comment: @ChristopherBruce well, this is not related to your problem, but they definitely should.

Comment: @ChristopherBruce is there a less obvious form of AV on your network, perhaps integrated into a webfilter or proxy that these downloads would be passing through?

Comment: Yes there is a web filter. I'll get with our sys admin and ask him to monitor traffic as I download the file.